# Generate Static HTML From Client-Side JavaScript Generated Site

Tags: javascript, html, static, generator, client-side

I'm generating an entire site using just an index.html with JS scripts.

The JS creates the HTML content based on JSON data received via the server-side API. This works great client-side and makes the site load speed and interaction very fast but there is a snag... when a crawler comes to index the page it will see a blank page.

The obvious solution is to provide an XML site map with static versions of all the pages. The problem is... how to generate static versions of each page when they are only generated client-side and all logic and templates are client-side?

This is not a new issue... I'm sure anyone generating pages dynamically client-side has hit this issue and solved it but I thought I'd ask the dev community before diving in and trying to solve this.

Comment: When you said it's work client side you mean that pages are not in a server and when you put the same pages in a server dosent work? the  api server have another domain that the server where you host the pages?

Comment: @Rolando The HTML on the site (all except the index.html which is just a body with script tags to load the JavaScript app) is all generated via JavaScript. If you loaded the index.html file without any JavaScript it would be a blank page.

Comment: The site works? but the google ajax crawler dosen't see?

Comment: if is that see : http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=174992  the crawler will modify each AJAX URL such as www.example.com/ajax.html#!mystate to temporarily become www.example.com/ajax.html?_escaped_fragment_=mystate. We refer to the former as a "pretty URL" and the latter as an "ugly URL".

Comment: you can use tampermonkey or greasemonkey to both iterate though all th e pages on the site by crawling links and download the pages locally. you then copy all the downloads to the server. or, you could rig up a way for the userscript to save to your server using a php/asp catcher.

Comment: @Rolando Yeah I did a thorough Google before posting and checked out those issues, the issue isn't around AJAX urls. The site is built from client-side HTML templates using jsRender. Because of this there are no links on the page for the crawler to follow. Even if I provided a site map to Google the links would still just load a blank html page. In the Article you linked to you'll notice that it states you have to provide an "HTML snapshot of this URL" - this is the crux of the issue - how to generate that snapshot when the site is generated entirely client-side!

Comment: @dandavis There are around 27,000 "pages" of the site and it's likely they will need constantly updating so a manual option is out of the question (unfortunately) - I had considered "crowd sourcing" the updates in the sense I can grab the final HTML for a URL and get any client to upload the client-side version for me via jQuery but that is so insecure!

Comment: well, a userscript like i described can run 24X7 on a cheap desktop, the only thing to automate is uploading to the server, which is very possible using a variety of solutions. 27,000 could be done overnight.

Comment: @dandavis This is true... seems like such a hack though! Still... it's probably pretty fast compared to PhantomJS. Automating the client is easy for sure... that I can do no problem.

Comment: i don't see it as a hack at all, it's simple and pretty much the epitome of scripting. what do we want? what the browser does! whose got it? the browser! where do we want it? the server! can our machine's JS talk to the server? yes! rah rah rah... seems better to do it ourselves than crowd source it. i've robotic-ally migrated a CMS w/80,000 entries with tampermonkey, and we liked it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## 2019 Update

Tech has moved on significantly. I would encourage anyone looking to create SSR (server-side rendered) **and** client-side web apps in one isomorphic code base to take a look at the excellent Next.js.

Next.js wraps React with a server-side routing and rendering system built in Node.js, defines a standard interface to getting data for pages on server and client, and comes with some out of the box features that make it one of the best choices (IMHO) for both SSR and CSR web applications.

Oh... and they have a great tutorial too!

## 2013 Answer

I've managed to generate static pages from the client-side output by using PhantomJS and capturing the HTML output after the page and all JS has finished loading/executing. This method is slower than I would like and unlikely to scale well but it's the only option that I can think of so far.

The site already receives over 10,000 page views a day with over 8,000 unique visitors so pages get updated regularly as new comments / posts are created and then these changes are added to a queue which gets process in a separate server to generate static pages with Phantom.

The only other way I can think of doing this is to create a Node.js process that uses the same jsRender library and builds HTML output from the template files based on some data, but this would be time consuming to set up and would not generate the exact same output that the dynamic site creates. Google may frown on me serving it static pages that don't really represent the dynamic version that "normal" visitors can see.

This seems like an unsolvable issue. Either I generate the pages entirely server-side, or crawlers cannot index the pages. :(